# Click on all elements found - React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-testing-library

I'm trying to click on all elements found with the same data-testid, but what i've tried doesn't worked.

```
get elements() {
  return this.screen.findAllByTestId("test");
}

async clickAllElements() {
  const elements = await this.elements;
  elements.forEach(element => {
    userEvent.click(element);
  });
}
```

If i log the "elements" variable it shows an array with 2 elements, but it doesn't click on them.

Comment: How are you checking the elements are clicked?

Comment: If i click one or more elements some values are changed in the components, so i check that with screen.debug(), if i click one element i can see the changes, but if i loop and try to click on all of them i can't

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this?